# Can I standardize all data before doing cross validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I am doing a small machine learning project.

I doubt that, can I standardize all of the data, X, first (except the label, Y).
I only saw the developer standardize the train set with `fit_transform()` and test set with `transform()` after splitting the train - test set

example of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('../../dataset/dataset_experiment_1.csv')
X_no_stdize = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,86].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_no_stdize)

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)

print('XGBoost')
model = XGBClassifier(booster='gbtree', objective='binary:logistic', learning_rate=0.2, max_depth=3)
f1_score = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring3)
print('f1-score: ', f1_score.mean(), ' +- ', f1_score.std())
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: yes you can standardize all your `X` data if all your features (columns) are of numeric dtypes

Comment: But if you are planning on testing the performance by splitting the data into train and test, then standardizing all data will leak some information to the model. Thats why always `'fit()'` on train and only `transform()` on test. transform() will also standardize the data but will use the information from the training data during fit() to do so.

Comment: As @VivekKumar explained it is bad idea to standardize all your data if you are planing to apply Cross Validation because that way your model which you will be training on Train Data will get some leaked info on your test Data. You should standardize Train Data and and than go with Cross Validation.
Now when you have decided on the Model to put on Test set you should transform your Test set with the transformations learned on training Data before applying your model on Test set